# procedure or function sp_updatestudentdetail was not supplied in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();

    if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_updatestudentdetail", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Textemail.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenum", Textmobilenum.Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EC_id", Textcurricular.SelectedValue);

        try
        {
            string filename = Image1.ImageUrl.Substring(Image1.ImageUrl.IndexOf('/')+1);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));

            foreach (string f in files) 
                 File.Delete(f);

            if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
            {      
                filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
                string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
                fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + uniqueFileName));

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (filename.Length > 0) ? "Images/" + uniqueFileName : string.Empty);
            }                    

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on EC_id and continue, "at the point `@image` row.. it shows `@image` was not supplied.

I tried something like that `com.ExecuteNonQuery();` changes the location to in try block.

Still it shows `@image` was not supplied.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: What happen if _fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length_ is zero?

Comment: if i place com.ExecuteNonQuery(); inside try block.. the break point didn't come  on fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length ..thanks

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!